# .NET #claims == 0 on all users

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

I am working on adding a user manager module to an application. It has a database and this database has a table of users and a table of user claims so that each user can have mulotiple claims. However, when I use usermanager to get Users.ToList() each user has its claims collection set to 0 entries even if the user in question does have claims listed in the user claims table.

It appears obvious to me that for some reason just doing usermanager.Users.Tolist() does not cause the code to consult the user claims table to check what claims each user has.

So the question is where and how to insert code that does exactly that.

Some potential issues with the existing code:
1. They have made a subclass of the IdentityUser so the UserManager is defined to be a usermanager of that subclass. But there is no explicit subclass of the usermanager. I am contemplating creating a subclass of UserManager for that purpose and if so I could override the Users property so that reading the Users list caused it to populate each  user entry with the claims for that user. Does that sound like a clean way of doing it?

2. In some other stack overflow question I saw a reference to a Startup.Auth.cs file. We have a Startup.cs file but no Startup.Auth.cs file, should we make one?

Thank you in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the ASP.Net identity template when you created your project, you must have a Startup.Auth.cs, it could be hidden as a sub-file of Startup.cs, or in the App_Start folder etc.

If trying to bypass the `UserManager`, when you request your user from EF, make sure you `.Include(...)` the claims property. For example:

```
dbcontext.Users.Include(u => u.Claims).FirstOrDefault(...);
```

Better yet, you should be using `UserManager`:

```
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var claims = userManager.GetClaims(userId);
```